# Cross domain AJAX not working, even with wildcard origin

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, sinatra

On my website, http://bitalarm.com, I am trying to integrate Bitstamp prices through their API with requests in Javascript from the client side. I have been getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/. Origin http://bitalarm.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I changed my headers in the Sinatra app that runs Bitcoin Alarm to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a wildcard. I know this is set because of curl:

```
$curl -I http://bitalarm.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 2253
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-08-29)
Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2013 01:39:08 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Unfortunately, I still get the errors. Should I change other parts of the header to get this to work?

Here is the javascript that accesses that API. It is just a GET request with jQuery.

```
url: 'http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/',

getPrice: function(callback){
    $.get(app.api.bitstamp.url, function(data){
    callback({
        value: data.data.last_local.value,
        display: data.data.last_local.display
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the javascript where you're making the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API site (www.bitstamp.net) does not have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set.

The CURL example you provided is a request made to your site; the request to the bitstamp site, whereas the actual CURL request to bitstamp shows something slightly different:

```
$ curl -I http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2013 01:58:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.bitstamp.net:443/api/ticker/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_156_99025=nashNbLsX1Eg32pAgDkqAiy5cVIAAAAAz1umCC4nKSJlj6EdKqS70w==; path=/; Domain=.bitstamp.net
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_99025=A7ePN/kMSnWVCoZjb2CgRSu5cVIAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABYCnOINrGBVtDw+Rx+PQs1; expires=Fri, 30 Oct 2015 08:44:52 GMT; path=/; Domain=.bitstamp.net
X-Iinfo: 11-97249264-97249266 NNNY CT(123 -1 0) RT(1383184683823 1) q(0 0 1 1) r(2 2) U6
X-CDN: Incapsula
```

Note that there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set here, which means the browser will not allow the request to go thru.

I'm assuming you don't have access to the bitstamp.net server, in which case you'll need to use a server-side proxy to fetch the data via ajax.  I'm guessing from your example CURL request that your server-side code is written in Ruby, [so this Ruby example may be helpful towards implementing such a proxy](http://jamesstarmer.com/blog/cross-domain-json-without-jsonp-using-a-ruby-proxy.html).

Answer (score -1):

You are trying access an API from another domain http://www.bitstamp.net/, so your domain http://bitalarm.com should be white listed in the API server.

Please check the configuration in the API server.